# Как правильно читать полученные данные?

Tags: delphi, tcp

Как правильно читать полученные данные?

Делаю так

```
IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn
```

Так клиент читает построчно, но на последней строки зависает.

Если на сервере ставить в конце каждого сообщения `'\n'`, тогда всё ок, правильно это?

По идеи он должен считать всё что было передано сервером!

`delphi XE3`

Comment: data := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn(#$D#$A)

если сервер ответит "Hello" - то клиент не выйдет с ReadLn(#$D#$A) а если сервер ответит "Неllo" + #$D#$A - тогда в data запишиться Hello

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй читать через `IdTCPClient1.Socket.ReadLn` данные.

Comment: пробывал - тоже самое зависает

Comment: ты в цикле что ли читаешь данные с сервера? Или просто на строке данной зависает программа?

Comment: Логично, что зависает, так как ждет перевода строки. Поэтому обычно делают так, что бы знать, сколько именно данных нужно прочитать - например до перевода строки или передают размер, или до специального символа.

Comment: Да, попробуй сначала передавать размер данных которые надо передать. А после совпадения размера полученного объема данных с переданным размером завершать чтение данных компонентом IdTCPClient.

Comment: Вопрос был  то правильно ли я читаю данные, а не почему зависает.

чтение данных делается в цикле и в потоке.

data := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn(#$D#$A)

если сервер ответит "Hello" - то клиент не выйдет с ReadLn(#$D#$A)
а если сервер ответит "Неllo" + #$D#$A - тогда в data запишиться Hello